# Splitting a long sentence to a short one when a certain word is found in Java

Tags: java, text, split

Greetings All;

I have a LinkedList of type String which contain some words like [from, to, in, then, however]
and I have a text file which contain long sentences.
what i want to do is to split those sentences in shorter sentences when one of the above words is found.

what I have did so far that I made a linked list that contains the words, and another linked list that contain the long sentences in the file.
I don't know how to split the long sentence?

I have tried this:

```
int indexofsw = 0;
       for (int k = 0; k < LongSentence.size(); k++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < SWords.size(); j++) {
                    if (LongSentence.get(k).contains(SWords.get(j))== true) {
                        indexofsw = LongSentence.get(k).indexOf(SWords.get(j));
                        System.out.println(LongSentence.get(k).substring(k,indexofsw));
                        break;

                    }
                }
            }
```

but it doesn't returns a shorter sentence.

Any Ideas please?

Comment: String does have a [`split`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

test.java, to get you started:

```
public class test{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    String[] splitWords = {"to", "in", "from", "then"};
    String str = "this from that";
    String[] tmp;
    for (String splitTkn : splitWords){
      tmp = str.split(splitTkn);
      if (tmp.length > 1){
        System.out.println(tmp[0].trim());
        System.out.println(tmp[1].trim());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

output:

```
this
that
```

Comment: what if i want to iterate over all the list of words [from, to, in, then, however]  I have tried this but it gives an exeption ` String[] temp = null;
         for (int k = 0; k < LongSentence.size(); k++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < SWords.size(); j++) {
                temp = LongSentence.get(k).split(SWords.get(j));
                System.out.println(temp[k].trim());
            }
        }`

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like?

```
Set<String> wordsToRemove =
String sentence =
List<String> words = Arrays.asList(sentence.split(" "));
words.removeAll(wordsToRemove);
```

Comment: thank you for replying but i mean to split on each word in the list not on space.

Answer (score 0):

Try using replace:

```
public class test {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    String[] splitWords = {"to", "in", "from", "then"};
    String string = "this from that";
    for (String splitWord : splitWords) {
      string = string.replace(" " + splitWord + " ", System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    }
    System.out.println(string);
  }
}
```

output:

```
this
that
```